# create list<string> in method call

Tags: c#, list, methods

I'm calling a method and want to send a list of strings in it. Is it possible to create the list while calling the method?

Something like this:

```
methodToCall(int myInt, {"Hello", "World"});
```

and then retrieve it like this:

```
public static void methodToCall(int myInt, list<string> myStrings)
{
}
```

Comment: You might want the `params` keyword (but it works with arrays, not `List<T>`)

Comment: @DanielMann: What I've shown. Tried google it, but no useful result. So tried here. And yup, got an answer in three minutes. Great ^^

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it looks like this:

call

```
 methodToCall(2,new List<string>() {"Hello", "World"});
```

and the function called like this

```
 public static void methodToCall(int inInt, List<string> inList)
```

Answer (score 2):

Modify your method signature as:

```
public static void methodToCall(int myInt, List<string> myStrings)
{ }
```

and then call it like:

```
methodToCall(5, new List<string> { "Hello", "World" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can create an array like this : `new [] {"Hello", "World"}`

It would result in

```
methodToCall(myInt, new[] {"Hello", "World"});
```

and the signature on the other side can look like

```
public static void MethodToCall(int m, IEnumerable<string> s){}
```

Comment: best answer for promoting more generic interface

Comment: @imsoconfused - also exactly not what the OP asked for... "list" was asked for.  This answer is also strange because it talks about creating an array and then has it as an Enumerable in the Method decl.

Comment: @Hogan and looking at his question, seems like he could learn a bit more, which is the whole point of this site

Comment: @Hogan You can pass a list to an `IEnumerable`. Or an array. If you _really_ need a list, you can still use an `IList`, which is still compatible with the array declaration.

Comment: @imsoconfused - I agree, but this answer does a bad job of making it clearer since it mixes up 4 different terms and uses them interchangeably.  With some edits to explain what it all means (eg difference between List, array and IEnumerable) it would be much better.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - Don't put that here... explain it in your answer.  Make it all clear and I'll up-vote :D

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault - If you would explain your way, I would check this as the answer. But so far Hogan has the more direct answer, without to much extra going on.